# retry until condition not satisfied on karatedsl

Tags: karate

I have two files, first for a.feature contains

```
Feature: xxx
Scenario Outline: xxx 
* call read('../../RunnerFeature/RunnerMobile.feature') {"customer_id":<customer_id>, "RC":<RC>,"id":<id>,"product_code":<product_code>}
Examples:
|"081290070020"|'00'|16|"1"|
```

and other file b.feature contains :

```
Scenario: get detail transaction
Given path '/transaction/' + response.transaction_id + ".json"
And header Accept = 'application/json'
And header Authorization = 'Basic' + ' ' + expected
And retry until response.response_code == '#(RC)'
When method get
Then status 200
```

but I always get `retry condition not satisfied: response.response_code == '#(RC)'`
but when I change this code below :

`And retry until response.response_code == '#(RC)'` to 
    `And retry until response.response_code == '00'` , it works perfectly...

so, why I always get `retry until condition not satisfied` when I use this '#(RC)' ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#(foo)` notation is meant only for JSON and XML. When you have a variable in scope, you can use it "directly" as follows:

```
And retry until response.response_code == RC
```

If you still face problems, just ensure that the value of `RC` is set correctly by `print`-ing it.

Refer the documentation please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

Comment: ook, done...
I just accepted your answer for my previous question :D

Comment: hoo, it works perfectly, I just knew if I use #(foo) only for JSON and XML, and RC for variable in scope...
Thank you very much :D